# DB2 How to select dates for the previous 2 months

Tags: sql, db2

I am using Oracle SQL developer on DB2 and have a date field stored as an integer e.g. 20210401

I want to bring back results for the last 2 months and have tried this:

select * from table where date > add_months(sysdate, -2)

This is producing error 206 saying it is not valid in the context used.

Does anyone know how to convert the data column or have an easier way to filter for the last 2 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
select * 
from table
where date > INT (TO_CHAR (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 2 MONTH, 'YYYYMMDD'));
```